# Cleaner way to gather multiple inputs from user

Tags: python, input, try-catch

I've learned exception 'catching' on one in python

```
while True:

  try:

    int(input("Enter a number: ")
    break

  except ValueError:

    print("That isn't a number")
    continue
```

If I had a lot of user_inputs in a piece of code it would look like I don't know what I'm doing (which I don't fully)

Is there an easier, less 'disgusting' way of doing this.  If so, how?

Comment: `continue` just let you skip the rest of the current iteration; but it is already at the end, so it is not needed. Other than that, it's not so disgusting in my opinion...

Comment: What i mean by 'disgusting' is that i would have to rewrite what is literally the same thing over and over again, which looks like im using copy & paste over and over again

Comment: thats what functions are for

Comment: "Same thing over and over again" leads to the language-independent concept of packaging up code into functions. See iCodez's answer. It's not Python-specific by any means.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using `try/except` for this task is idiomatic in Python because it follows [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).  The only problem is that you are writing the same input-gathering code for each input.

You can make your code reusable by putting it in a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
def get_int():
    while True:
      try:
          return int(input("Enter a number: "))
      except ValueError:
          print("That isn't a number")
```

Now, whenever you need to get an input from the user, you can just call the function:

```
int_1 = get_int()
int_2 = get_int()
```

---

You can even make it so that the `get_int` function accepts a custom prompt for each input:

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
      try:
          return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
          print("That isn't a number")
```

This allows you to make your program more intuitive.  For example:

```
height = get_int('Please enter a height: ')
width = get_int('Please enter a width: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

From [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29);

> Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming
> language.Its design philosophy emphasizes code
> **readability**, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in
> fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or
> Java.The language provides constructs intended to enable
> clear programs on both a small and large scale.
>
> The core philosophy of the language is summarized by the document "PEP
> 20 (The Zen of Python)", which includes aphorisms such as:
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly
>
> Explicit is better than implicit
>
> Simple is better than complex
>
> Complex is better than complicated
>
> Readability counts

So don't rush, first complete tutorials and learn the basic, you'll see Python is the most 'clear' and less 'disgusting' language.